# How to re-draw in swing without removing previously drawn things

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

So, I wanted to implement DDA algorithm to draw lines using java with swing but I have a little bit problem here. To draw each pixel I am using `fillRect(X,Y,1,1)`. So, I need to draw for different positions of `X` and `Y` to draw a line. In order to update newly drawn 'pixel' I  am using `revalidate()` and `repaint()` but this seem to remove my previously drawn pixel and I just see a point. As a work-around I commented out `super.paintComponent(g)` in my `paintComponent(Graphics)` but this does not seem like a good solution because then I am unable to set background color and I see line being drawn if I slow it down using `Thread.sleep()` (other wise I just see a dot) . Here's the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Painter extends JPanel {
    private double x1,y1,x2,y2;
    Painter(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;

    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect((int)x1,(int)y1,1,1);
    }

    public void drawLine() {
        double DX = (x2-x1);
        double DY = (y2-y1);

        double steps = (Math.abs(DX) > Math.abs(DY) ) ? Math.abs(DX) : Math.abs(DY);

        double xIncrement = DX/(steps);
        double yIncrement = DY/(steps);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                x1 += xIncrement;
                y1 += yIncrement;
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

}
```

And from my `main()` I call it like

```
JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Graphics");
Painter dpl = new Painter(0,0,533,333);
jFrame.add(dpl);
jFrame.setSize(720,480);
jFrame.setVisible(true);
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
dpl.drawLine();
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You should call `drawLine` from a separate thread. `repaint` is safe to be called outside from the EDT and you block the EDT by calling `drawLine` (which contains `sleep()`) on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve the problem with an offscreen image so that you don't have to omit the `super.paintComponent();`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Painter extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage offi;
    Graphics offg;
    private double x1,y1,x2,y2;

    Painter(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;

    }
    @Override
    protected synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(offi,0,0,this);
    }

    private void draw(){
        if(offi == null){
            offi = (BufferedImage)createImage(getWidth(),getHeight());
            offg = offi.getGraphics();
            offg.setColor(Color.black);
            offg.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        }  
        offg.setColor(Color.RED);
        offg.fillRect((int)x1,(int)y1,1,1);
    }

    public void drawLine() {
        double DX = (x2-x1);
        double DY = (y2-y1);

        double steps = (Math.abs(DX) > Math.abs(DY) ) ? Math.abs(DX) : Math.abs(DY);

        double xIncrement = DX/(steps);
        double yIncrement = DY/(steps);        
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {           
            x1 += xIncrement;
            y1 += yIncrement;

            /*try{
                Thread.sleep(50); //sleep if you want it to be animated
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
            draw();            
            repaint();
        }  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Graphics");
            Painter dpl = new Painter(0,0,533,333);
            jFrame.add(dpl);
            jFrame.setSize(720,480);
            jFrame.setResizable(false);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            new Thread(() -> dpl.drawLine()).start();;
        });
    }

}
```

The reason that you saw sometimes a line and sometimes just a single point is that swing merges consecutive `repaint()` calls that happen within a short time frame.

Comment: @Sigma: this is the solution that you want (+1). You might consider wrapping the `g.drawImage(...)` in an if block, `if (offi != null)` if there's any chance that it could be null.

Comment: No need for the "synchronized" keyword on the paintComponent(...) method. All Swing painting code is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Comment: @camickr I think since I use a separate animation thread in my answer, the code in `paintComponent()` might has to be synchronized along with the code in `draw()`. Synchronizing `paintComponent()` alone makes indeed no sense, but I think it may be cleaner to make `draw` synchronized as well than removing the synchronized from `paintComponent()`, because `BufferedImage` is not fully threadsafe.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep track of your current points to redraw them.

```
private final List<ArrayList<Integer>> points = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(Color.black);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    for(ArrayList<Integer> point : points) {
        g.fillRect(point.get(0),point.get(1),1,1);
    }
}

public void drawLine() {
    double DX = (x2-x1);
    double DY = (y2-y1);

    double steps = (Math.abs(DX) > Math.abs(DY) ) ? Math.abs(DX) : Math.abs(DY);

    double xIncrement = ((double)DX/(double)(steps));
    double yIncrement = ((double)DY/(double)(steps));
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            x1 += xIncrement;
            y1 += yIncrement;

            points.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add((int)x1); add((int)y1);}});
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

This is a bad design but i made it to demonstrate what you have to do. The best case is to create a Point class and store your points in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: It's up to you how you want your line to be drawn.